# Syntax and formatting for an array

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently going through the Angular guide since the last time I used it was when I had developed an app in ES5. I'm confused about this one particular part:

```
export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

is this new syntax for setting an object? Why is there a colon, then brackets when its setting the array of 'heroes'?

Wouldn't it be something like...

```
const heroes = [  { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Comment: `: Hero[]` is a type annotation, that's **TypeScript**. [tag:angular] is very different from [tag:angularjs].

Comment: Ohhh, alright. Thanks for the links. I assume employers expect you to know both?

Comment: I can't speak for all employers, read the job spec and/or ask them.

Answer (score 0):

Writing Hero [] is like stating that the constant HEROES must be an array ([]) whose elements will have the structure that is defined for Hero.

Comment: hey! thanks this answers my questions perfectly... just read up a bit more on typescript an this explains it well.